# How to compare array of objects with array of strings?

Tags: arrays, object, filter, element

How to compare array of objects and array of strings then return array of element which is not matched
ex: var test= [{name: 'a', value: '1'}, {name: 'd', value: '2'},{name: 'b', value: '2'}, {name: 'c', value: '3'}];
var strings = ['1', '2','4'];
},
then it should compare strings with value in values, though duplicates existed in test it should return relevant keys and if not found perfect match then return the value from the strings

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since no language is specified i will write a solution in Python.

```py
listOfStrings = ["1", "2", "4"]
listOfObjects =  [{name: 'a', value: 1}, {name: 'b', value: 2}, {name: 'c', value: 3}]

    def myfunc(strings, objects):
        listOfNotMatchedElemets = []
        objValues = [x.value for x in objects]
        for string in strings:
            if int(string) not in objValues:
                listOfNotMatchedElemets += int(string)
        return listOfNotMatchedElemets
```

Comment: Hi ,I would like to know in javascript

Comment: Hi @kuppililakshmiprasanna, are you still in need of a solution or did you manage to solve your issue?